# Generate a series of monotonically increasing and decreasing integer values without duplicating them at the boundaries of the intervals

Tags: postgresql

I also need to generate monotonically increasing and decreasing integers of a user-defined interval, without duplicating values at the interval boundaries in one column of the table.

The desired result for k intervals of 10 digits, except for the first interval is shown in the figure below in the top conditional row.

[image]

Figure

The difficulty I encountered is that the first interval consists of n+1 digits, then the situation is ordered by n digits.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to adapt the [answer given to you previously](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/337260/23721) by excluding repeated values:

```
WITH s AS (
  SELECT n, x, lag(x) OVER (ORDER  BY n, ((n%2 * 2)-1) * x) l_x
  FROM   generate_series(1, 3) n  -- how many times? 
     , generate_series(0, 5) x  -- number range
)
SELECT x
FROM s 
WHERE x <> coalesce(l_x, -1)
ORDER  BY n, ((n%2 * 2)-1) * x;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/V1oYBkEg)

Comment: Thanks again ErwinBrandstetter and @mustaccio, you have helped me a lot....

Answer (score 0):

This is how custom SQL functions are born.

Create the first function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS generate_numbers_interval_as_descending_order(
    k integer,
    i integer)
 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_numbers_interval_as_descending_order(
    k integer,
    i integer)
RETURNS TABLE (x integer) AS 
$BODY$
WITH 
s AS (SELECT n, x, lag(x) OVER (ORDER BY n, ((n%2 * 2)-1) * x) l_x 
      FROM generate_series(1, i) n, generate_series(0, k) x)
SELECT x FROM s WHERE x <> coalesce(l_x, -1) ORDER BY n, ((n%2 * 2)-1) * x;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

Run

```
SELECT generate_numbers_interval_as_descending_order(5,3)
```

Create the second function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS generate_numbers_interval_des_ascending_order(
    k integer,
    i integer)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_numbers_interval_des_ascending_order(
    k integer,
    i integer)
RETURNS TABLE (x integer) AS 
$BODY$
WITH 
s AS (SELECT n, x, lag(x) OVER (ORDER BY n, ((n%2 * 2)-1) * x) l_x 
      FROM generate_series(0, i-1) n, generate_series(0, k) x)
SELECT x FROM s WHERE x <> coalesce(l_x, -1) ORDER BY n, ((n%2 * 2)-1) * x;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

Run

```
SELECT generate_numbers_interval_des_ascending_order(5,3)
```

The authors and developers of the body functions is © Erwin Brandstetter (user:3684) and @mustaccio (user:23721)

(-: FOGS :-)...